# jQuery datepicker doesn't appear, but the element appeared at the corner of the screen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm currently having an issue with the jquery datepicker.

Here's my code :

```
<div class="form-group print" id="div_tempat_print" style="margin-top:50px;text-align: center;display:none"> 

    <div style="top:10%;width:100%;padding-top: 5px;color:black;background-color:#E0E0E0;">

    <div class="print" id="show_remark" style="margin-left:300px;">
        <div style="width:100%;text-align:left;font-weight:bold" >Remark</div>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="remark_all" style="width:500px;height:75px;"><?php echo $data_by_id['remark'] ?></textarea>
        <?php if($data_by_id['task_id_reference']=='' && strpos($data_by_id['site_id_destination'],'WDHL') !== false) { ?>
        <div style="width:100%;text-align:left;font-weight:bold">Planned Inbound Date</div>
        <input class="form-control" style="width:500px;" type="text" name="planned_inbound_date" id="planned_inbound_date">
        <?php } ?>
    </div>  
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#planned_inbound_date").datepicker(
            {format:'yyyy-mm-dd'}
        );
    });
</script>
```

Here's how it looks on my website :

[image]
In that pic, I'm positioning my cursor by clicking in the planned_inbound_date input field. Here's how it looks normal in the other form :

[image]

If you need another code, I'll update my post :) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the z-index option because it's hiding in the background.